# Am I using these MOSFETs correctly?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, solenoid

I am designing and testing a circuit that charges a capacitor to around 50V using a boost converter when 'ARM' is high, then discharges it through a solenoid when 'FIRE' is high. ARM and FIRE are outputs from an Arduino Uno (5V logic level). The arduino GND pin is connected to the ground in the schematic shown below. Here's what happened. I build the capacitor charging portion and got the capacitor to charge when ARM was sent. But then when I assembled the entire circuit, the top MOSFET starts smoking when ARM is high. Switched it out with the other mosfet and now I'm out 2 mosfets. I'm just wondering if there's something obvious I'm missing here or something wrong with my design. The boost converter had no datasheet and is kind of a black box for now, maybe that has something to do with it. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have BAT+ grounded and not BAT-? It's not necessarily wrong (assuming the "50 V BOOST" block is an isolated converter), but it's strange.

Comment: Is the boost converter input and output isolated?

Comment: Since the MOSFET's start smoking I assume BAT- and VOUT- are connected.

Comment: Does the boost converter have isolated output?

Answer (score 0):

FQP30N06 is not a logic level FET so you can never switch it fully on with the Arduinos 5 V. Furthermore, it's a N-channel and you connected it before the load not after leading to even less on-state but higher resistance.

The third problem is that the boost converter got BAT- and VOUT- connected, and since you have BAT+ connected to GND, 9 V is fed through the MOSFET under plenty of resistance, killing the FET. And if you managed to turn the FET on, it it would likely kill the 9 V source instead (it can take 30 A).

And one more thing, that solenoid have no flyback diode but should probably be one there.

Comment: What do you mean by 9V fed through MOSFET "under plenty of resistance"? Do you mean plenty of current? Also, doesn't the MOSFET set the drain current? How could it be over-currented if it sets its own current based on V_gs etc. Thanks for your help

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you elaborate on why having the MOSFET before the load leads to higher resistance?

Comment: @Epix "Also, doesn't the MOSFET set the drain current? How could it be over-currented if it sets its own current based on V_gs etc." – It does limit its own drain current, but it doesn't do so in an intelligent way. The MOSFET doesn't know that if it allows too much current through at too high a voltage, it will cook itself.

Answer (score 0):

One likely problem is that the \$V_{GS}\$ you're applying to those MOSFETs, which is 5 V, is much lower than what they're designed for. The datasheet for the FQP30N06 promises that if \$V_{GS} \le 2 \ \mathrm{V}\$, then the transistors will have a very high resistance, and if \$V_{GS} \ge 10 \ \mathrm{V}\$, then the transistors will have a very low resistance. But at \$V_{GS} = 5 \ \mathrm{V}\$, the datasheet basically makes no promises about what will happen. The worst-case scenario is that the MOSFET acts as a medium resistance, and thus conducts a significant amount of current but also maintains a significant voltage, which will case the MOSFET to absorb a significant amount of power, heat up, and start smoking.

The easiest solution may be to use a logic-level MOSFET, one where the datasheet *does* promise that it will have a very low resistance when \$V_{GS} = 5 \ \mathrm{V}\$. (If the boost converter has BAT- and VOUT- connected internally, you may need to use a p-MOSFET instead of an n-MOSFET.) Another option to consider is to use a BJT instead of a MOSFET.

Also, as pointed out in [MiNiMe's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/690623/65892), you need to have a flyback diode for that solenoid, or else the solenoid will fry MOSFET2 the first time that MOSFET2 turns off.

Comment: I will look at other MOSFETs. But let's suppose this is the only MOSFET I can use. The max power dissipation rating is 79W, which seems good enough in connection with a 9V power supply, even with resistance. Would the power dissipation be approximately V^2/R in this case?

Comment: @Epix Well, using this MOSFET as-is isn't the worst idea I've ever heard. Note that the 79 W power rating only applies if you can somehow manage to keep the case temperature at 25 °C, which is going to be practically impossible. Theoretically, one option would be to aim for a case temperature of 100 °C, which would allow you to waste up to about 39 W in the MOSFET. You'll need a heat sink capable of dissipating about 0.5 W/°C, which is probably going to be pretty big. In practice, if you can afford to get the wrong FET along with a heat sink, you can probably afford to just get the right FET.

Comment: Another option would be to use this MOSFET along with a gate driver that can give it 10 V, or some type of tiny 10 V power supply along with a second transistor (which could be an NPN transistor) to turn it on and off. Either of those would probably be a lot easier than the heat sink. In any case, the best formula to use for power dissipation here is probably \$P = I V\$, or, to be more precise, \$P = I_D \ V_{DS}\$. Note that the boost converter may not work at all if the power supply is a high-impedance supply such as this MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Would there be a downside to using an NPN in place of the upper mosfet? I assume since connecting a 9V battery is a basic task, does it just boil down to design preference? Seems like it would be easier for the arduino to supply a small current to turn it on instead of a voltage.

Comment: @Epix Using an NPN in place of the n-MOSFET sounds like a good idea to me. Remember the base resistor, of course. Depending on how much current the boost converter needs, you may need a Darlington pair. Also, if the boost converter isn't an isolated one, I think you'll need a PNP instead of an NPN.